# pandas query large dataframe slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (df_b ~50 mio rows, 3 columns) I need to query, to see if the subset of the dataframe contains things from a list. I takes 1-2 sec. each look up in the large dataframe df_b (do df_b.query()). Any suggestion how I can speed it up / doing it another way?

Below my sample code

```
import pandas as pd
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'M':[11,11,11,11,11,11,33,33,33,44,44],'C':['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b'],'W':['AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC','AA','AA']})

df_scope = pd.DataFrame({'M':[11,22,33,44,55],'W':['AA','CC','CC','CC','QQ']})

my_list = {'a','b','z'}

for row in df_scope.itertuples():
    k = df_b.query('M == '+ str(row[1]) +' and W == "'+ row[2] +'"')
    c_found = len(k[k['C'].isin(my_list)])

    if c_found > 0:
        print("PN: " + str(row[1]) + " Yes")
    else:
        print("PN: " + str(row[1]) + " No")
```

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to use numpy ```isin```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood you right, but you can do `.merge` and then `.groupby`:

```py
x = df_b.merge(df_scope, on=['M', 'W'], how='right')
t = x.groupby('M')['C'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(my_list).any())
for i, v in zip(t.index, t):
    print('PN: {} {}'.format(i, 'Yes' if v else 'No'))
```

Prints:

```
PN: 11 Yes
PN: 22 No
PN: 33 Yes
PN: 44 No
PN: 55 No
```

---

Anoter solution, without `.groupby`:

```py
df_b['tmp'] = df_b['C'].isin(my_list)
x = df_b[df_b['tmp']].drop_duplicates(subset=['M', 'W']).merge(df_scope, on=['M', 'W'], how='right')

for i, v in zip(x['M'], x['tmp']):
    print('PN: {} {}'.format(i, 'No' if pd.isna(v) else 'Yes'))
```

Prints:

```
PN: 11 Yes
PN: 22 No
PN: 33 Yes
PN: 44 No
PN: 55 No
```

Comment: `x.groupby('M')['C'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(my_list).any())` is bottleneck.